# comparison of several variables via logical AND in operator <=>

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

for example, there is a structure with two fields:

```
struct point {
    float x, y;
    
    bool operator ==(point p) { return x == p.x && y == p.y; }
    bool operator <(point p) { return x < p.x && y < p.y; }
    bool operator <=(point p) { return x <= p.x && y <= p.y; }
    bool operator >(point p) { return x > p.x && y > p.y; }
    bool operator >=(point p) { return x >= p.x && y >= p.y; }
};
```

Comparison operators check the condition through logical AND for each variable, how should the <=> operator look like so that its result does not differ from these operators?

I already tried to move all operators to the new <=> back when compilers only began to support it, but neither then nor now have I found a way to implement what I wanted.

The only more or less working version of the code that I found:

```
std::partial_ordering operator<=> (const point& p) const {
   std::partial_ordering c = x <=> point.x;
   if(y <=> point.y != c) return std::partial_ordering::unordered;
   return c;
}
```

It produces correct results for < and >, but incorrect results for <= and >=. For example, `point(0, 0) <= point(0, 1)` is `true` but here `<=>` returns `unordered`.

Comment: @chrysante You are correct. I missed that part. Deleted comment.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "incorrect results for <= and >="? An example would help.

Comment: _"The behavior of a program that attempts to compare a `partial_ordering` with anything other than the integer literal `​0`​ is undefined."_ - so `y <=> point.y != c` doesn't seem defined since `c` is a `partial_ordering` but `y <=> point.y` is not the integer literal `0`

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's definitely defined.

Comment: @Barry: it seems like cited from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/partial_ordering , and while anyone can edit cppreference, I typically find it reliable.

Comment: @Barry for example `point(0, 0) <= point(0, 1)` the <=> operator will return false, while the example operator will return true

Comment: @TedLyngmo: the same source says *Comparison operators are defined between values **of this type** and literal 0* , so the comparison should work as Barry said.

Comment: @vtable Thanks. That's the kind of information that belongs in the question (went ahead and added it for you).

Comment: @Barry & THomasWeller Ok, I see, thanks.

Comment: I am still thinking about how those comparisons might be useful. `<` checks whether P is in quadrant 1 relative to *this* and `>` checks whether P is in quadrant 3 relative to *this*. What about the other quadrants? Aren't they interesting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the issues with your relational comparisons is that they're not actually consistent. Namely:

```cpp
bool operator ==(point p) { return x == p.x && y == p.y; }
bool operator <(point p) { return x < p.x && y < p.y; }
bool operator <=(point p) { return x <= p.x && y <= p.y; }
```

The definition of `p <= q` is `(p < q) or (p == q)`. But that's not what's actually going on here.

Considering your example where `p` is `(0, 0)` and `q` is `(0, 1)`:

- `p == q` is `false` (they're not the same)
- `p < q` is `false` (because while `p.y < q.y`, it is not the case that `p.x < q.x`)

Yet, nevertheless:

- `p <= q` is `true` (because `p.x <= q.x` and also `p.y <= q.y`)

That's inconsistent.

Your `operator<=>` is actually correct, it just helped expose the fact that your `operator<=` and `operator>=` are incorrect.